# Compilation issue with typescript file

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

I'm new to typescript and was trying to work on it where in I came across this issue, where I saved a file using `.ts` extension and instead of recognizing the file as a typescript file,the system is recognizing it as a Transport Stream file. I have already installed all the typescript files using node. Whenever I try to compile the code the error displayed is as follows:

> PS D:\WorkSpace\typescript> tsc basics.ts tsc : File
>   C:\Users\mn\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because
>   running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
>   about_Execution_Policies at
>   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

At line:1 char:1

> - tsc basics.ts
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
>   ```

This is how the file appears in the folder:

[Folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXeNb.png)

Answer (score 10):

1. Run the Windows PowerShell as RunAsAdministrator
2. type `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
3. exit and run compiler again

Answer (score 4):

For now, I suggest removing all .ps1 files from your npm bin folder.

Sometimes changing the execution policy is not a good practice. A more restricted Execution policy (RemoteSigned) helps users from unintentionally running malicious code.

The issue is still open in the npm/cli repository, labeled as 'Needs Discussion' [Necessity of Powershell Script Support for Global Packages](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/470).

Comment: For me, the `tsc.ps1` it was in `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 0):

- CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

I got the same error in visual studio. But using command prompt  it has been solved

Thank you